# How to update edited values to Microsoft Access Database using OleDb connection for MS DataGrid?

Tags: c#, database, wpf, datagrid, oledb

We have bind datagrid with OleDb connection database. And while changing the cell value,  we are updating the database in RowChanged using DataTableAdapter.Update method. But on closing and starting the application again, modified value is not updated in datagrid.

Below is the code snippet that I am using for updating the database

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=EmployeeDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
        myDataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee", conn);
        builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        ds = new DataSet();
        conn.Open();

        myDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");
        myDataTable = ds.Tables["Employee"];
        myDataTable.RowChanged += MyDataTable_RowChanged;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(
            "UPDATE Employee SET EmployeeName = @EmployeeName, EmployeeArea = @EmployeeArea, EmployeeDesignation = @EmployeeDesignation, EmployeeAge = @EmployeeAge " +
            "WHERE ID = @ID", conn);


        // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "EmployeeName");
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeArea", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "EmployeeArea");
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeDesignation", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "EmployeeDesignation");
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeAge", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "EmployeeAge");
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "ID");
        myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = command;



        conn.Close();
        msDatagrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["Employee"].DefaultView;
        Binding nbe = new Binding();
        nbe.Source = ds;
        nbe.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        nbe.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        nbe.Path = new PropertyPath("Employee");
        nbe.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
        msDatagrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, nbe);
        msDatagrid.Items.Refresh();
    }


    private void MyDataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
    }
```

Could any one please suggest how to update the database that is bound with the datagrid?

Regards, 
Shobika.

Comment: Did you try myDataTable.AcceptChanges();

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the way that you had suggested. But I am facing stackOverflow exception when tried to call myDataTable.AcceptChanges(); in MyDataTable_RowChanged event.

Comment: I think what is happening ti the Update is changing the row which is firing another RowChangedEvent.  so in the RowChangedEvent unregister the event myDataTable.RowChanged -= MyDataTable_RowChanged; Before the update and then register again the update.  The event really should be the DGV updating not the DataTable.